# JetBrains plugins : autocomplete suggestions based on JSON resource directory

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

When developing some apps on Android Studio I've seen that the IDE provide some suggestions for string.

[image]

Strings displayed were stored on `src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

Actually, I'm working with Flutter on IntelliJ IDEA and Dart does not provide any kind of autocomplete suggestions for strings.

[image]

So I'm looking for a plugin which can display suggestions based on a resource directory (where resource's files are JSON). I hope for one which could be configured to suggest only key of JSON file for example.

```
    {
      "key_one_which_will_be_displayed_as_suggestion": "random_data_one",
      "key_two_which_will_be_displayed_as_suggestion": "random_data_two",
    }
```

Is there some plugin's developers who can help me :) ?

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest trying [hippie completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/auto-completing-code.html#hippie_completion) (`Alt+Slash`) - it searches for words in all open files

Comment: No it's out of scope. What i talk it's the suggestion zone which is empty.
Hippie completion is a blind replacement...